# Calculate Total Price with Symfony (Solved)

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following problem with shopping cart. I don’t know where to place the calculation, so it can update total price dynamically (Such when the cart item is removed, or the quantity updated). Because I need to call `updateTotalPrice()`  method almost everywhere, but I don’t want to repeat the code that many times

So far it look like this
[image]

CartService

```
class CartService extends AbstractController
{

    private CartRepository     $cartRepository;
    private ManagerRegistry    $managerRegistry;
    private CartItemRepository $cartItemRepository;

    public function __construct(CartItemRepository $cartItemRepository, CartRepository $cartRepository, ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry)
    {
        $this->cartItemRepository = $cartItemRepository;
        $this->cartRepository = $cartRepository;
        $this->managerRegistry = $managerRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * Get Cart by ID
     *
     * @return Cart|null
     */
    public function getCartByUserId(): ?Cart
    {
        /**
         * @var User $user
         */
        $user = $this->getUser();

        return $this->cartRepository->findOneBy(['customer' => $user->getId()]);

    }

    /**
     * Create Cart for Customer
     *
     * @return Cart|null
     */
    public function createNewCart(): ?Cart
    {
        $entityManager = $this->managerRegistry->getManager();
        $cart = new Cart();
        /**
         * @var User $user
         */
        $cart->setCustomer($this->getUser());
        $entityManager->persist($cart);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $cart;
    }

    /**
     * @param Cart $cart
     * @param Product $product
     * @return CartItem|null
     */
    public function isProductInCart(Cart $cart, Product $product): ?CartItem
    {
        return $this->cartItemRepository->findOneBy(['product' => $product->getId(), 'cart' => $cart->getId()]);
    }

    /**
     * Add new product to cart
     *
     * @param Cart $cart
     * @param Product $product
     * @param int $quantity
     * @return void
     */
    public function insertProduct(Cart $cart, Product $product, int $quantity): void
    {
        $entityManager = $this->managerRegistry->getManager();

        $insertProduct = new CartItem();
        $insertProduct->setCart($cart)
                      ->setCart($cart)
                      ->setQuantity($quantity)
                      ->setProduct($product);
        $cart->addCartItem($insertProduct);
        $cart->setTotalprice($cart->getTotalprice() + $insertProduct->getQuantity() * $insertProduct->getProduct()->getPrice());
        $entityManager->persist($insertProduct);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }

    /**
     * Update item's quantity
     *
     * @param CartItem $cartItem
     * @param int $quantity
     * @return void
     */
    public function updateCartItemQuantity(CartItem $cartItem, int $quantity): void
    {
        $entityManager = $this->managerRegistry->getManager();
        $cartItem->setQuantity($quantity);
        $entityManager->persist($cartItem);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }

    /**
     * Remove specific product from cart
     *
     * @param int $id
     * @return void
     */
    public function removeProductFromCart(int $id): void
    {
        $product = $this->cartItemRepository->findOneBy(['product' => $id]);
        $entityManager = $this->managerRegistry->getManager();
        $entityManager->remove($product);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }

    /**
     * Set or update total price
     *
     * @param Cart $cart
     * @param float $totalprice
     * @return void
     */
    public function updateTotalPrice(Cart $cart, float $totalprice): void
    {
        $entityManager = $this->managerRegistry->getManager();
        $cart->setTotalprice($cart->getTotalprice() + $totalprice);
        $entityManager->persist($cart);
        $entityManager->flush($cart);
    }

    /**
     * Add Product to Cart
     *
     * @param Product $product
     * @param $cartItem
     * @return void
     */
    public function addOrUpdateProduct(Product $product, $cartItem): void
    {
        $cart = $this->getCartByUserId();

        if (!$cart instanceof Cart) {
            $cart = $this->createNewCart();
        }

        $isProductInCart = $this->isProductInCart($cart, $product);

        //If product doens't exist, insert it inside cart. If exist, update quantity and add message
        if (!$isProductInCart) {
            $this->insertProduct($cart, $product, $cartItem->getQuantity());
            $this->addFlash('productAdded', 'Product added to Cart');
        } else {
            $this->updateCartItemQuantity($isProductInCart, $cartItem->getQuantity() + $isProductInCart->getQuantity());
            $this->updateTotalPrice($cart, $cartItem->getQuantity() * $cartItem->getProduct()->getPrice());
            $this->addFlash('productAdded', 'Product already in cart. Quantity Updated');
        }
    }
```

OrderController (That's the cart)

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

/**
 * @IsGranted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")
 */
#[Route('/cart', name: 'cart.')]
class OrderController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * Show current Cart
     *
     * @param CartService $cartService
     * @return Response
     */
    #[Route('/', name: 'show_cart')]
    public function showCart(CartService $cartService): Response
    {
        $cart = $cartService->getCartByUserId();

        return $this->render('cart/index.html.twig', [
            'cart' => $cart,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update existing cart item quantity
     *
     * @param CartItem $cartItem
     * @param int $quantity
     * @param CartService $cartService
     * @return Response
     */
    #[Route('/updatecartquantity/{id}/{quantity}', name: 'updatequantity')]
    public function updateCartQuantity(CartItem $cartItem, int $quantity, CartService $cartService): Response
    {
        $cartService->updateCartItemQuantity($cartItem, $quantity);

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cart.show_cart'));
    }

    /**
     * Remove product from cart
     *
     * @param CartService $cartService
     * @param int $id
     * @return Response
     */
    #[Route('/removeitem/{id}', name: 'removefromcart')]
    public function removeFromCart(CartService $cartService, int $id): Response
    {
        $cartService->removeProductFromCart($id);
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('cart.show_cart'));
    }

}
```

Product Controller (Shows the product -> After choosing quantity can be inserted inside cart

```
#[Route('/product', name: 'product.')]
class ProductController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * Show Product, and add to cart
     *
     * @param Product $product
     * @param CartService $cartService
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    #[Route('/showproduct/{id}', name: 'showproduct')]
    public function showProduct(Product $product, CartService $cartService, Request $request): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(CartItemType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $item = $form->getData();
            $item->setProduct($product);

            $cartService->addOrUpdateProduct($product, $item);
        }

        return $this->render('product/showproduct.html.twig', [
            'product' => $product,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use Symfony Event listeners/subscribers : https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html.

Comment: This is off-topic but your CartService probably should not be extending AbstractController.  I'm guessing you did this to get access to the user.  The security docs show how to access the user from a regular service.  You might also just consider calculating the total price whenever you actually need it instead of trying to keep it up to date.

Comment: @Cerad Good Point! Thanks for your time and help! I'll try it asap!

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding `showCart()` method, which instead inserts and updates values in database, it runs only, when I want to display Cart.

```
    public function showCart(): ?Cart
    {
        $cart = $this->getCartByUserId();
        $cartItem = $this->cartItemRepository->findBy(['cart' => $cart]);
        $totalprice = 0;
        foreach ($cartItem as $carti) {
            $totalprice += $carti->getQuantity() * $carti->getProduct()->getPrice();
        }
        $cart->setTotalprice($totalprice);

        return $cart;
    }
```

Comment: You should consider moving this core calculation logic to your entities. 
That seems wrong to be able to set the cart's price "manually". This price should always be the sum of cart lines total, no matter what. :)

Comment: @Mcsky Makes sense, since Entity does not need to map the exact table. But, should I persist and flush, to insert the value to database?

Comment: it depends there are benefits from 2 solutions ^^ If you store the total value in the database you can do some ordering/filtering with SQL and you don't have to calculate the price to display it, but you need to call a "recalculate" method every time you modify something on the cart that can impact the total. In another hand, if you don't store the price in db, you're sure the price is up to date with your entity state. IMHO both solutions are correct